# How to vizualise Nan in a Tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have created a Tensorflow dataset from a Pandas dataframe the following way:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train,Y_train))
```

I have verified that my dataframe has no NaN AND no NULL, but when I use tfdbg I can see that there are NaNs in my tf train_dataset (`lt -f has_inf_or_nan` returns `[11.787]  28.89M   Const   tensors/component_0:0` and component 0 is my train_dataset).

How can I find where are these NaN in order to debug what went wrong during the convertion ?

I have tried `tf.is_nan(train_dataset)` but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset'> to Tensor. Contents: <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((45,), (2,)), types: (tf.float64, tf.uint8)>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: what type of data in dataset (images !!)

Comment: numerical values between 0 and 1 (normalized features), 45 columns

Answer (score -1):

this problem happen to me with images because I use the false index when I generate the datasets

`NaN` value means you have `NULL` value inserted in dataSet

Comment: unfortunately no, print (x.isnull().values.any()) and isnan both return false. Moreover the question is about displaying NaN index from a tf.data.Dataset :)